# How to evenly space out a string based on screen size in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have set up a class that reads inputs from a file and puts them into an array. Each item is set up in this format x:y:z with x being sequential throughout the 
array. I have code that puts the array into JList<> and then displays it with a Jscrollpane.  I have used a Gridbag layout and have it set to where it will find the screens size and set the container to the width and 2 thirds the height of the screen. Now to my question: is there a way to dynamically replace the ":" in each item of the array to seperate all three items so that x is on the far left y is in the middle and z is on the far right? here is my two public classes:

```
import java.awt.*;        
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;


public class QueGui extends Frame implements WindowListener {
    //variables
    private JList<String> Jquelist;
    private Frame mainFrame;
    private Label headerLabel;
    private Label statusLabel;
    private Panel controlPanel; 
    GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    int currentque;
    int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();   
    final static boolean shouldFill = true;


    public QueGui() {
        mainFrame = new Frame("Java AWT Examples"); //makes frame
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 

        //following gets the que list
        queinput q = new queinput();
        ArrayList<String> quelist = new ArrayList<String>();
        quelist=q.quereporter(); 
        //this converts it to a box for display
        DefaultListModel<String> DLMquelist = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        for( String que : quelist ) {

            DLMquelist.addElement(que);
        }
        Jquelist = new JList<>(DLMquelist);

        //this tells me when a que is selected
        Jquelist.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    final List<String> selectedValuesList = Jquelist.getSelectedValuesList();
                    String[] currentque = selectedValuesList.get(0).split(":");
                }
            }
        });
        //this publishes the frame
        GridBagConstraints pane = new GridBagConstraints();
        if (shouldFill) {
                //natural height, maximum width
                pane.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        }
        pane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        pane.weightx = 1.0;
        pane.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        pane.insets = new Insets((height)/3,0,0,0);
        pane.ipady = (height);
        mainFrame.add(new JScrollPane(Jquelist), pane);

        mainFrame.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY); 
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(this);  
        mainFrame.setTitle("Que thingy"); 
        mainFrame.setSize(width, height);           
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new QueGui(); 

    }




    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
        System.exit(0);  // ends the program
    }

   //needed for for the compilier
    @Override public void windowOpened(WindowEvent evt) { }
    @Override public void windowClosed(WindowEvent evt) { }
    @Override public void windowIconified(WindowEvent evt) { }
    @Override public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent evt) { }
    @Override public void windowActivated(WindowEvent evt) { }
    @Override public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent evt) { }
}
```

and

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
public class queinput{

    public ArrayList<String> quereporter()    {
    ArrayList<String> ques = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the file name with extention : ");
        File file = new File(input.nextLine());

        input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            ques.add(line);
        }
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return(ques);
    }
}
```

I know I could probably add in spaces myself but I want this to work on other computers as well as mine. Sorry if this is a dumb question I have looked around for an answer but I could have just been googling wrong. Thanks for any help

[EDIT]
Also does anyone know how to change the background color of a jscrollpanel? Have not found a working answer yet :(

Comment: Seems like you simply want to display x, y, and z into separate columns which is what a JTable is specifically designed for. Why not use one?

Comment: Oh...to change the background color of a JScrollPane I believe you need something like: jScrollPane1.getViewport().setBackground(Color.RED);         jScrollPane1.getViewport().setOpaque(true);

Comment: @DevilsHnd Thanks for the background color and is there a way to make it so that I can only select rows not cells in jtable? That is why I chose Jscrollpane because I can get which row is selected and change which row is selected based on user input

Comment: @DevilsHnd Also how could I easily split each item of my list and add them to the table while keeping them in the same row?

Comment: to make your table act as a list use something like:  jTable1.setFocusable(false);  jTable1.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);

Answer (score 1):

Okay...because there are so many questions I will need to place this into an answer.

Use a JTable if you want to set your data into configurable columns. After all...that is exactly what it's designed for. It even has its own scroll bars :)

To change the background color of a JScrollPane I believe you need something like:

```
jScrollPane1.getViewport().setBackground(Color.RED);
jScrollPane1.getViewport().setOpaque(true);
```

To make your JTable act and look like a list you can do something like this:

```
jTable1.setFocusable(false);
jTable1.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);
```

To add a Row to your JTable you can place the desired values for each row column into a Object Array then use a small custom method to add the data to JTable. Let's call the custom method **addRowToJTable()** and you could use it something like this:

```
// Just tossing in some integer values into the array.
Object[] values = {22,32,42};
addRowToJTable(jTable1, values);
```

And here is our custom method:

```
private static void addRowToJTable(JTable theTable, Object[] rowString) {
    JTable tbl = (JTable) theTable;
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tbl.getModel();
    model.addRow(rowString);
    tbl.updateUI();
}
```

If you have your data within an ArrayList and you want to ad it to your JTable then you can do something like this (assuming each element within the ArrayList consists of 3 colon delimited items):

```
// Example ArrayList...
ArrayList<String> myItems = new ArrayList<>();
myItems.add("10:12:14");
myItems.add("11:13:15");
myItems.add("16:17:18");

for (int i = 0; i < myItems.size(); i++) {
    Object[] values = myItems.get(i).split(":");
    addRowToJTable(jTable1, values);
}
```

**EDIT: Using Arrow Keys To Navigate JTable Rows.**

As you have already noticed, when your JTable has the **setFocusable()** property set to ***false*** then the keyboard cursor (arrow) keys will not allow you to navigate up and down the table rows. The easiest way to overcome this problem (in my opinion) is to simply **not** set the **setFocusable()** property to ***false*** :) Unfortunately though, when you do this there is this annoying focus border around a column cell. Well, just get rid of the cell focus border but to do this we need to utilize a custom Table Cell Renderer like the one show below (just add this small subclass to the very bottom of your application class), we'll just call it **NoBorderTableCellRenderer** :

```
class NoBorderTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(final JTable table, final Object value,
            final boolean isSelected, final boolean hasFocus, final int row, final int col) {
        final boolean showFocusedCellBorder = false;
        final Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, 
                            showFocusedCellBorder && hasFocus, row, col);
        return c;
    }
}
```

Now, instead of having:

```
jTable1.setFocusable(false);
jTable1.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);
```

you would have:

```
jTable1.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
jTable1.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new NoBorderTableCellRenderer());
jTable1.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);
```

Comment: thanks so much and I love the output except When I set jTable1.setFocusable(false); I can not use the arrow keys to move down the list. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: @MathMXC, See the added code in my answer in regards to your new problem.